# Does this function create a new String everytime this is called?

Tags: java, string

```
public String toString()
{
     return "NotSubscribed";
}
```

We are trying to limit String's creation in our application after the objects are instantiated. So, just wondering if this creates a new String every time this toString is called. It might be a bad question, but I don't know the answer. Please suggest.

--

I just remembered that if a String is created, it is stored in the String Pool and after that it is always retrieved from the pool without being re-created. Am I right?

Comment: Not all Strings are stored in a "string pool", but literals in programs are (as Mr Skeet describes).  So your function does not cause a new String to be created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that won't create another string each time. String constants are *interned* - so actually the constant "NotSubscribed" will refer to the same string object throughout your code, not even just every time this method is executed.

From [section 3.10.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1, §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value. String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

However, in your edit:

> I just remembered that if a String is created, it is stored in the String Pool and after that it is always retrieved from the pool without being re-created. Am I right?

No, that's not right. Only string *constants* are interned by default. For example, every time you run this code:

```
public List<String> createStrings() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add("foo" + i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

... that will create another 10 strings.

Comment: is my interpretation of section 15.28 correct that if I would remove the `+ i` from your example (`list.add("foo")`) only one `String` would be created ?